How to control jq error message when input is not valid json?
jq prints error message like the following when the input is invalid.
$ jq . <<< "xxx"
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

I want to control what is printed when the input json is not valid. For example, I may want to prepend something to the original error message. How can I achieve this with jq?
XXX:parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0


It's not really possible, unless you recompile jq itself. The error is happening before your jq program transforms the json, already during parsing.

What is your goal, why do you want to prefix errors with another string?

Assuming you are running from a bash shell, you could capture the error output and process it any way you want. In the example below I am putting "xxx:" in front of every line and sending the output to standard error:
jq . <<< "invalid json" 2> tmpfile.$$
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/xxx:\1/' < tmpfile.$$ 1>&2 
rm -f tmpfile.$$


As a one-liner : jq . <<< "invalid json" 2>&1 | sed 's/^/xxx:/' 1>&2

The only reason I didn't go that route, is that I thought the requester may only want to modify the output if there is an error. If you do it as a one liner, you are combining the normal output with the error output so if there isn't an error, it would modify the normal output. I guess I should have been some logic around the 'jq' command to illustrate that idea (i.e. if jq . file 2> tmpfile.$$; then :; else sed -e 's/\(.*\)/xxx:\1/' < tmpfile.$$ 1>&2; rm -f tmpfile.$$; fi

It's not really possible, unless you recompile jq. The closest I can offer is the following, but you don't have access to the original error message:
jq -R 'try fromjson catch error("my custom error")'

